# Can't search for -infavorites:mine

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, search

Negating the `infavorites:mine` advanced search operator doesn't work. Favorited questions still show up in the results. This is regardless of whether the `-` is put before `infavorites` or before `mine`, and regardless of whether this is the only search term or in combination with another. (But I didn't test all combinations of these.)

Answer (score 1):

Negation works only for regular search: tag, term or phrase as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Advanced search operators can't be negated, and that's not a bug.

If you want to search all questions you *don't* have in your favorites I fear that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Changed from [bug] to [feature-request]. I recommend signalling on that search help page that that advanced search operators can't be negated.

Comment: Fair enough, personally I don't think they'll do it but one can never know. :)